# hiding or not displaying a dataset coming form an API

Tags: reactjs

I have an endpoint api and some objects are missing values.  How can I hide them or get them not displayed.  I only want to display a complete set. some objects do not have url and I do not want to display them
thanks for your help

Comment: can you be more specific on how your data looks like and how you are rendering it in the UI .

Comment: on what params are you trying to hide your response?

Comment: I am trying to get data id, name, url, and zone.  some objects don't have urls it just comes with empty string   imgUrl": " ",

Answer (score 0):

just check the object have value or not like 
if in your object key and value pair is missing you can use this way

```js
 { Object.keys(obj).length == 2 && <div><p>{ obj.name }</p><p> { obj.phone }</p></div>}
```

or if key is comming but value is missing then check for that particuler value.